# В чем ошибка в коде при роутинге на go?

Tags: html, golang, http, маршрутизация

есть простой код на Го (2 странички с переходом между ними):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func index_page(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
  http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
}

func login_page(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "тест")
}

func handleRequest() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", index_page)
    router.GET("/login", login_page)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
}

func main() {
  handleRequest()
}
```

хмтл индекса:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>login or auth?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Стартовая страничка</h2>

            <a href = "login_page.html">
                <input class="button" value="Войти"/>
            </a>
            <a href = "reg_page.html">
                <input class="button" value="Регистрация"/>
            </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Компилю, запускаю - страничка индекса открывается, при попытке перейти - валится с 404 ошибкой.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: у вас `login_page` крутится под ручкой `/login`, значит в html вам нужно указывать вместо  `<a href = "login_page.html">` указать `<a href = "/login">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас `login_page` крутится под ручкой `/login`, значит в html вам нужно указывать вместо `<a href = "login_page.html">` указать `<a href = "/login">`